# Uploading photo Rest API without posting to wall

Tags: facebook, api, rest, upload, photo

I'm doing a FB app where users are able to upload a photo to a photo album that is created at the same time. My problem is that I only want the photos to go into the album avoiding the post of the same photos on the users wall and in the users news feed. 
Not sure if that's possible or if there's a workaround.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Quoting the docs: "Requires the publish_stream permission." I think if it asks for this permission, it's going to be automatically posted on the user's wall.

Comment: Thanks manuel. I'm currently trying to find a workaround, maybe deleting the post from the news feed/wall? For some reason, my app uploads 6 photos to the user's profile/photos and the news feed will post sometimes only 3 pictures in one row and sometimes it will duplicate the posts...

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue - uploading 5 photos to an album, but sometimes that 'blah blah blah added new photos' notification will come up as many as 4 times on the user's wall. I haven't found a way to upload all photos in one shot - as a 'batch upload' right - so I'm starting to think that retroactively deleting those notification posts might be the only way to handle it.

Comment: did anyone figure this out or is there a possible workaround? i am facing the exact same problem right now.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use the parameter `no_story=1` within your call.

This is not documented on [Album](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) or [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), but is on [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and it works for Photos as well.

Related to: [facebook upload photo without news feed post? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100321/facebook-upload-photo-without-news-feed-post-possible)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to work around this is to delete the stories (posts) generated for each photo upload. To answer another question in the thread you can do batch photo uploads, see this blog post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493 that explains how to do this using Batch Requests.

Assuming you used batch requests (or even if you upload one at a time) you can follow this process:

1. After uploading the photos through Graph API, note the id of the photo(s) uploaded.
2. Make a call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=object_id&access_token=youruseraccesstoken  to get your latest wall post information. You may choose to pass on a limit parameter so you do not get too many results.
3. Loop through the results, looking to match the object_id to the information saved in step (1). Note the corresponding id, these are the wall post id(s).
4. For each wall post id found in step (3) issue an HTTP DELETE to https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID with an access_token that has publish_stream access.

The wall posts should be gone but the photos still in the album.