# facebook upload photo without news feed post? Possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use Graph API to upload photos to facebook without a news feed post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can bypass the post-if you upload the photo to the user's album, and then post your own news story to the user's album, for example "here is my new photo from XXXXXXX application" the profile will only show the news post, and the photo upload. **Make Sure** to first publish the photo, then publish the news story.

Answer (score 10):

use `no_story=1` parameter in your photo upload.

from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

> If you would like to suppress the
>   story that is automatically generated
>   in the user's feed when you publish a
>   photo (usually because you plan on
>   generating your own), you can add a
>   no_story=1 parameter. In this case,
>   the user will receive a notification
>   that your application has uploaded a
>   photo.

Comment: This has been deleted from the docs, don't know why, but still works. User docs still have this info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/