# Upload photo to facebook fan page wall with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This [tutorial](http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html) has helped me writing the following code; with it I am able to upload a photo to an album on my fan page. How can I make it so that I can publish to the fan page wall and not just upload the photo to the album? I am looking in implementing the required code within this below.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  require_once 'library/facebook.php';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'My APP ID',
   'secret' => 'My Secret KEY',
   'fileUpload' => true
  ));
  #It can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
  #Change to your token.
  $access_token = 'My access token';
  $params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
  #The id of the fanpage
  $fanpage = 'My Fan Page ID';
  #The id of the album
  $album_id ='My Album ID';
  $accounts = $facebook->api('/My User Name/accounts', 'GET', $params);
  foreach($accounts['data'] as $account) {
     if( $account['id'] == $fanpage || $account['name'] == $fanpage ){
          $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
     }
  }

 $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
 if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)){
   if( !in_array($_FILES['pic']['type'], $valid_files ) ){
       echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';
   }else{
       $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
       $args = array(
          'message' => 'This photo was uploaded via WebSpeaks.in',
          'image' => '@' . $img,
          'aid' => $album_id,
          'no_story' => 1,
          'access_token' => $fanpage_token
       );
       $photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
       if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
          echo '<p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$photo['id'].'">Click here to watch this photo on Facebook.</a></p>';
       }
   }
 }
?>

<div class="main">
    <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" /></p>
    <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `publish to the fan page wall and not just upload the photo to the album` what;s the diff?

Comment: the code above uploads the photo to the album without pubblishing the same photo on the actual wall. It simply uploads it in the album without to display the photo on the wall

Comment: Whenever you upload a photo, it will be published on the wall. You don't have to write anything extra for that

Comment: @Shadowfax it's not happening, I am telling you that it is not posting to the wall but only uploading to the album.

Comment: isn't that what 'no_story' => 1 is for?

Comment: thats' what my own answer said few months ago here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was not pubblishing actually was due to the use of `no_story=1` in my previous code as [they say in this other stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100321/facebook-upload-photo-without-news-feed-post-possible)